# Which layer checks for Access Token in an Implicit Grant OAuth 2.0 flow?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

***Context***: 
User is trying to access a website 'A' in browser but,'A' relies upon another web application 'B' (Authentication Server) to authenticate & authorize the user using "Implicit Grant" OAuth 2.0 flow.

***Question:***
When a user access a web page in website 'A' for the 1st time, how does the website 'A' knows that this 1st time request does not have a valid access token and then redirect this request to Website 'B' ?

> Does the 'Webserver' of website 'A' makes this check of access token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPLICIT FLOW SOLUTIONS**

This solution is used by web apps where no code executes on the web server - and your Web UI is a Single Page Application - is this definitely the same as your solution?

- 'Web Site A' will be your client side Javascript UI - users login and then get an access token
- 'Web Application B' - the authentication server - will be a 3rd party system that issues access tokens to your Javascript UI
- The API will be your server side code - it receives access tokens from the client side UI, validates the token, then returns data to the UI

**SERVER SIDE WEB APP SOLUTIONS**

If your solution is different to the above then it sounds like you have a server side web app instead - in this case the Implicit Flow is not the right solution.

**IF YOU DEFINITELY HAVE A SINGLE PAGE APP**

There is a bit of a learning curve to using OAuth 2.0 and Open Id Connect with Single Page Apps. I would recommend the excellent [OIDC Client Library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) which will do a lot of work for you.

Out of interest I've written a detailed blog + code samples around OAuth 2.0 solutions, including SPAs. I hope you can just browse it to improve your understanding - maybe start with [This Overview](http://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/).

Comment: thank you. Yes, the 'Website A' is going to be SPA relying upon API (running as Microservices in PaaS) for server side code. In this case, the entire application (including the screen to be displayed after login) is downloaded to browser but, the post login screen gets rendered in browser only after the javascript gets a valid Access Token. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Also, does the SPA have the client-id embedded/hard-coded in it ? and is visible for the ones who do a view source in their browser ?

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript application "website A" probably keeps the access token and its expiration time somewhere - for example in the [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). So on load, the application can check the presence of an access token and its expiration time. The expiration time is delivered along with the token in a redirect URL ([`expires_in`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2) parameter) from the auth provider.

Comment: what happens if the user has bookmarked a page and is directly accessing it. This request might directly hit the webserver of "Website A" without an access token. How does Website A decides to redirect to the Authorization Server (Website B) ?

Comment: Access tokens are usually required only for API calls (from JavaScript), so it's up to the application developer to check the access token when the application starts (browser page loads). There should also be a response error handler implemented, which could react to HTTP 401 (result of invalid or no token) response by redirecting user to the auth provider.

Comment: >usually required only for API calls<  that is why my confusion. Here the teams are proposing to use the implicit grant authorization for logging into the Website A. So now, how/where (Web/App server) should we check for the access token in the 1st request for the static pages ?  Can this check be done by the Webserver with any configuration or should i load the page and only then let the page (javascript) do this check ?

Comment: Let the HTML load and do the check just in JavaScript. Checking it at the server is possible but usually doesn't make sense since the JavaScript application knows where to redirect if access token is missing.

Comment: sure, that is the conclusion i seem to be coming. I was mainly trying to rule-out that, such a check CANNOT be done at/by the Web Server. Post login, these SPA pages will be invoking API/Microservices running in cloud. So, we don't want to host an App server, just for this purpose of checking Access Token in the incoming request and redirect to Authorization server.